# Want to have the same web method for different pages.

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have a requirement to have a auto complete text box in one of the web page.
I am doing a jQuery Ajax call to web method in the code behind to get the data to that text box. That is working fine. But I have to have the same functionality in the different web pages.

How can I use same web method with out duplicating the code.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a web service will allow you to refactor your code out of the code behind for the page and use it in any other pages that you may need.